# How can I add a listener in my preference fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, listeners, preferencefragment

I need to set a onPreferenceChangeListener to my preference fragment, but I don't know how could I do it... here is my code

```
public class PrefsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    Context context;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        context = this.getActivity();
        context.setTheme(R.style.myStyle);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        view.setBackgroundColor(0x96000000);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your PrefsFragment need to implement the OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener interface, for example:

```
public class PrefsFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {...
```

You can then implement the onSharedPreferenceChanged method:

```
@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key)
{
    //do something 
}
```

}

Make sure that you register the listener, too:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    super.onPause();
}
```

Comment: Absolutely - glad it helped :)